# Alert message if enter is pressed when focus in on a particular textbox out of 2 textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Before proceeding with my question, i would like to share a html with you all

```
<form name="m_domain" action="domains.php#searchdomain" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
      Enter search name
      <input type="text" name="search_domain" id="search_domain"/>
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="submit" value="search" name="submit_search"          
      id="submit_search"/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
      Enter replace name
      <input type="text" name="replace_domain" id="replace_domain"/>
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="submit" value="replace" name="submit_replace"
       id="submit_replace" onclick="return validate()"/>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Now here's the actual problem arise..

for this line

```
<input type="button" value="replace" name="submit_replace"
           id="submit_replace" onclick="return validate()"/>
```

when the button is clicked, the validation occurs, but when our focus in on the textbox `id="replace_domain"` and we are clicking enter, the validation doesnot happen(case is simple, the validation is on onclick rather than onsubmit. Now i cant change it to onsubmit, because there are some hell lot of problem in doing that)

now here comes the issue.

What i try to do is that, i am trying to put a check whether enter is pressed by binding a function on the keyup method for the textbox `id="replace_domain"`.

```
$('#replace_domain').bind('keyup', function(e) 
    {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This would work fine, but the problem is that, ssince there is one more textbox and a submit buton, so whenever i am pressing enter, the form submits

so i want to restrict submission on something like this.

1. if current focus was on textbox `#replace_domain` and the enter was pressed, then the form wont be submitted and the validation function will be called.
2. if the current focus was on textbox `#search_domain` and enter was pressed then the form will be csubmitted and validation wont be called.

How can i achieve this?

```
EDIT
```

I used this following code to work out, and it works partialy, but it just can't stop the form submission

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) 
{
    if (e.keyCode === 13) 
    {
        if($('#replace_domain').is(':focus')) 
        {
            alert("focus was on replace");
            e.preventDefault();   // still it refreshes the page
            return false;         // still it refreshes the page
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind both text box with `id`.

```
$('#replace_domain','#search_domain').bind('keyup', function(e) 
    {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) 
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: if the current focus was on textbox #search_domain and enter was pressed then the form will be submitted and validation wont be called.

Answer (score 0):

write this code:

```
if(e.keyCode==13 && $('#textboxID').is(":focus"){
--code------
}
```

This will solve your problem